# Use a view instead of a query that creates a result set equal to that view

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have 10 queries: TA, TB, ... , TJ that each generate a result set like:

```
date         Income    AccIncome     
--------------------------------    
2016-10-1     10          10         
2017-11-1     20          30
```

I need to execute a "JOIN" on the result sets of TA, ... , TJ on the date column that is the only one that is the same for all these queries. The problem I have is that this JOIN operation takes nearly 40 secs if TA, ... , TJ have only two rows. I am considering to use views for each TA, ..., TJ. Could this increase the performance of the JOIN operation? If so, can you tell why? Is there any other way to increase the performance of this JOIN operation? Thanks

To explain how the JOIN QUERY looks like:

Let Tx  be any of the tables TA, ... , TJ. Tx has the columns

```
 date  Tx.Colx1   Tx.Colx2
```

The JOIN op looks like:

```
SELECT TA.DATE, TA.COLA1, TA.COLA2, TB.COLB1, TB.COLB2, ... , TJ.COL1, TJ.COL2
FROM (QUERY A) TA
INNER JOIN (QUERY B) TB ON TA.DATE = TB.DATE
INNER JOIN (QUERY C) TC ON TA.DATE = TC.DATE
....
INNER JOIN (QUERY J) TJ ON TA.DATE = TJ.DATE
ORDER BY TA.DATE
```

Can the speed of this op be increased?

Comment: Views will not increase performance, can you paste the join query?

Comment: What is QUERY A, QUERY B, etc.?

Comment: Those queries produce a result set with columns   Tx.DATE, Tx.COLx1, Tx.COLx2 where x = A, B, ... , J. I was thinking to create views for those queries, but, I am not sure if this will increase the performance

Comment: Trying to clarify:  Each query (QUERY x) produce a result set with columns   Tx.DATE, Tx.COLx1, Tx.COLx2 where x = A, B, ... , J. I was thinking to create views for those queries, but, I am not sure if this will increase the performance.